# single.php não funciona

Tags: wordpress

Tenho na minha index 3 posts e quando clico para abri-la através de um permalink entra no single.php. até aí tudo bem, aparece o link no browser chamando o post, mas a página fica em branco.

Fiz assim no código single.php

---

Chamando o content-single.php

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left"><p>Data: <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right"><p>Por: <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p></div>
        </div>

        <p><?php the_tags('Tags: ', ' , '); ?></p>

        <h4><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h4>
    </div>
</header>
    <div class="content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Este é o single.php que utilizei para chamar o permalink

Comment: Isto não é uma resposta